# Alpha Channel in gnuplot palette

Tags: matplotlib, transparency, gnuplot, alpha

Is there a way to define an alpha channel in a palette in either gnuplot or matplotlib?

I'm trying to combine two scalar fields into one plot and so far came up with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set line colors with an alpha channel in the development version (4.7) of gnuplot.  You can set the alpha channel as the high bits of an RGB color specification.  For example,

```
plot x lc rgb '#AAAAAAAA'
```

draws a translucent gray line.

However, I'm not sure there is a way to do this for a palette.